# Custom List - Conditional formatting with images

Tags: 2013, custom-list, image

I've been browsing around trying to find out how to display an image within an IF statement on a page without it showing the link as text. Current my list looks like this:

[image: list]

with the 'statusimage' formula looking like this:

```
=IF(Status="Complete","https://website.com/teams/
Business Change/SiteAssets/Images/changelogo.png","Not Run")
```

How do i change it from showing the link to showing the actual image?

List setup for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It seems the trick is in the setup.

The data type at the bottom of the column setup must be changed to 'Number' rather than 'Single line of text'.

The forumla should look like this:

```
=IF(Status="Complete","<img src=https://website.com/teams/ Business Change/SiteAssets
/Images/changelogo.png>","Not Run")
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?
http://blogs.technet.com/b/jay/archive/2013/06/17/how-to-display-images-in-a-calculated-column-of-a-sharepoint-list.aspx

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'd used this before and it helped me some of the way. Thanks for the link :)